# Extracting EXIF data from android camera

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, exif

I'm writing an android app for detecting leaf spot diseases in plants. So I have to take photo of affected leaf. So when taking photos I have to take the photo within appropriate distance and appropriate brightness and contrast.

So when taking photo I have to show the brightness level and orientation on camera preview screen. So is it possible to show such information on camera preview?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Android's Camera App source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/camera/ui/IndicatorControlContainer.java#IndicatorControlContainer). It has all the controls on preview screen.

EXIF is useful *after* that image has been captured. I doubt it has brightness/contrast information.

```
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("<file>");
        exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);
```